# function hoisting in javascript

Tags: javascript

I was just trying function hoisting in js , I have a doubt in below code

```
// Case 1
var foo = function() {
    return 3;
}

// Case 2
function foo() {
    return 2;    
}
alert(foo());
```

Why case1 gets preference over case 2 always? case 2 never overrides case 1  , why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname

Comment: In function expression(case 1): only the variable foo is hoisted. Not the function body.

In function statement(case 2): the entire function foo is hoisted to the top

Comment: I don't think the "Usual" functions link answers this question.  The question is specifically about "hoisting," which @Shibbir explains in his comment.

Comment: @epascarello's link is a better reason for closing the question.